# Custom leave dialog in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a form where the user can edit stuff. If the user has some unsaved changed and wants to leave the page I want to give him a custom dialog, asking him if he is sure. If then the navigation should continue and the form changed flag should be reset, otherwise the user should stay at the page.

Here you can check my current higher order component which is checking this condition. It is working, but the function `leave` returns a string and react-router will then display that text in a native alert.

Is there a way that I can show my custom dialog in here? And can I also get a callback or similar of the alert, so that I can dispatch an event which tells the storage, that the latest changes are not important.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import connectRouter from "./connectRouter";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {injectIntl, intlShape} from "react-intl";

export default function confirmLeave(RouteTargetComponent) {

  @injectIntl
  @connectRouter
  @connect((state, routing) => {
    return {
      studies: state.studies
    };
  })
  class ConfirmLeaveHOC extends Component { // HOC = Higher Order Component

    static propTypes = {
      router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      route: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      intl: intlShape.isRequired,
      studies: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    leave = () => {
      if (this.props.studies.isChanged) {
        // lets stop the navigation
        return this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "confirmLeave" });
      }
      // continue the navigation
      return true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.leave.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
      // render the component that requires auth (passed to this wrapper)
      return (<RouteTargetComponent {...this.props}/>);
    }
  }

  return ConfirmLeaveHOC;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since customizing browser dialogs is not possible, you'll have to render a separate component (e.g bootstrap modal) and use a callback to determine which button was clicked, and what action to take.

I actually ran into the same problem you're facing very recently, and I was able to solve it by using `routerWillLeave` and using callbacks from another component.

#### Form component

```
routerWillLeave = (route) => {
  if (!this.waitingForConfirm && this._hasUnsavedChanges() && !this.clickedSave) {
    this.refs.confirmAlert._show( ((v) => {
      if (v) {
        this.context.router.push(route.pathname);
      }
      this.waitingForConfirm = false;
    }).bind(this));
    this.waitingForConfirm = true;
    return false;      
  }
}
```

The implementation of customized dialog like this one is unfortunately quite a pain in the back. I had to use 3 variables here to correctly control the desired behavior:

- `waitingForConfirm` - necessary to prevent the logic from running a second time when the user confirms to navigate out. Specifically, when the callback is run and we do `this.context.router.push(route.pathname)`, the `routerWillLeave` will run again(!), but since we've already confirmed navigation we must prevent this logic from running again.
- `_hasUnsavedChanges()` - checks if any input fields have changed (no reason to ask if there's no changes to be saved).
- `clickedSave` - don't ask for confirmation if the user clicked `Save` - we know we want to leave.

#### Dialog component

```
_show = (callback) => {
  this.callback = callback;
  this.setState({show: true});
}

_hide = () => {
  this.setState({show: false});
  this.callback = null;
}

_dialogAction = (input) => {
  if (this.callback) {
    this.callback(input);
  }
  this._hide();
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Button onClick={this._dialogAction.bind(this, true)}>Yes</Button>
    <Button onClick={this._dialogAction.bind(this, false)}>No</Button>
  );
}
```

Obviously, you'll have to customize the above snippets to fit your application, but hopefully it will provide some insight into how to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks the `this.context.router.push(route.pathname);` helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

A less complicated and more forward way is using a setRouteLeaveHook on your component. In accordance to the react-router v2.4.0

```
 
    import React from 'react'
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

    const Page = React.createClass({

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, () => {
               if (this.state.unsaved)
                 return 'You have unsaved information, are you sure you want to  
                 leave this page?'
           })
         }

         render() {
            return Stuff
         }

     })

     export default withRouter(Page)
```

[Here is the React-router version on their github page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.4.0/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md)