# Abort component unmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a multi step wizard form, where if a validation error occurs, I should not be able to go to next step.

The problem is, I can always use browser "Back" button go to previous step(a step which already passed the validation), change the input to some invalid data and then use the browser forward button back to the current step, that means I have "bypassed" the validation.

I'm not sure if I can do a check before leaving the current step and prevent leaving if something goes wrong, I would like to achieve something like

```
class Step2 extends Reac.Component {
// ...
compomentWillUnmount(){
    if(!form.isAllFieldsValid()){
         // display error and abort forward action
    } 
}
// ...
}
```

Diagram sample:

[image]

Normal flow would be 1, 2, 3, 4 ... so on.

The flow I'm trying to handle is, 1, 2, 3, then in the step2 screen, user press **browser** back button, make some invalid changes on step1 then press **browser** forward button. I'm trying to see if it's possible to hook the "forward" event, do the validation, and decide if I should stay step 1 with the error message or continue forward to step2.

The tricky part is by requirement, form data needs always be saved(in browser memory) when you leave each step so you can recover them back

Comment: So basically you want a condition to determine whether or not a route change should go through or not? If so, check out my previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37192984/2030321). The OP of that question wanted a confirm-dialogue, but you can just replace the Yes/No confirmation with an error message.

Comment: Sorry, I  added a diagram hope I can make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where the data goes once its valid? I would say, where ever it actually gets sent, just before that do a final validation there.

For example, if you have a final "submit" or "save" button at the end of the steps, you probably have a `onSave` with maybe a axios (or another async call):

```
async onSave() {
    // ~~ insert validation around here ~~ //
    const response = axios.post('foo/save', this.state.data);
    this.setState({
      complete: true, 
    });
}
```

It's not really an unmount task. Unmount is more intended to clean up any non-react things you did during mount (or elsewhere).

Comment: The data collected from the from will submit only on the last step. since we have a stepper to indicate which step went wrong, that's why I need to do validation on each page of the wizard. I have the application back/previous which work perfectly well, the only only is the browser back/forward buttons :s

Comment: So to clarify, what /should/ happen when they go back? Should they go to the page previous to the stepper altogether? Should the previous step be locked down?

Comment: back would go to previous step. the problem is more in forward, where I would like to do some stuff, then decide if should go to next route

Comment: hmm, its a bit tricky to get a grasp on what you are after then. is the question more about best practice for steppers? maybe throw up so wireframes to explain it better?